# write in stdin for a spawned child_process doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I am spawnning a java App (REPL for querying a local DB) using:

```
repl = = require('child_process').spawn('java', ['-cp', '...list of libs...', ,{ cwd: '...path to env...', env: process.env, customFds: [-1, -1, -1] });
```

The REPL loads fine because I can seen its outputs in stdout, but stdin.write commands don't go throught.  I can however write them directly the console window of the node process itself (which is weird since I didn't .resume() it).
I have printed out the stdin of the spawned process, it looks like this:

```
{ _handle:
   { writeQueueSize: 0,
     socket: [Circular],
     onread: [Function: onread] },
  _pendingWriteReqs: 0,
  _flags: 0,
  _connectQueueSize: 0,
  destroyed: false,
  bytesRead: 0,
  bytesWritten: 0,
  allowHalfOpen: undefined,
  writable: true,
  readable: false }
```

It seems there is no 'fd' defined, and also `.readable` returns false. How can this be resolved?
(this is all on a windows machine, node v0.6.6)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that [the `customFds` option was deprecated](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) specifically because they couldn't get it to work on Windows.

While an array of `-1`'s implies that it shouldn't be used, since the entire option is deprecated, try removing it entirely and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Tried it now, it had no effect. The thing is that if I choose to load some other process e.g., cmd.exe it works. It is as if the child process is "taking over" the node.js stdin input instead of creating its own, which seems odd.

Comment: In some ways, that doesn't surprise me. In order to run a Java program as a Linux daemon, [you have to wrap it in a nasty shell script](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/javaDaemonTest.sh.txt), redirecting all output to files to let you "disconnect" from it. Have you tried running ``cmd.exe`` and passing ``java`` as the first parameter for a similar wrapper around the process?